# macOS Safari version 12.0 - getUserMedia disabled?

Tags: macos, safari, getusermedia

I use Modernizr.getusermedia to test if a browser supports getUserMedia functionality. And I recently discovered that Modernizr.getusermedia returns false in Safari 12.0 (on Macbook).

I am fairly certain that in the past, it used to return true for safari. Could someone advise on what's changed and what I should do?

I can't imagine that getusermedia is actually disabled.

Comment: I have the same problem. Safari 12.0 (13606.2.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to use "getUserMedia" in Safari12. So you can use something like this:

```
// get "getUserMedia" function for other browsers
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    if (navigator.mediaDevices) { // if navigator.mediaDevices exists, use it
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(onGetUserMedia, onGetUserMediaError);
    } else {
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, onGetUserMedia, onGetUserMediaError);
    }
```